# Dynamic html onclick argument seen as text throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im building dynamic html based on results from a search
I have an onclick function that needs to accept a variable id as an argument but its throwing an error. It sees the argument as text thus throwing
an Uncaught ReferenceError: 1 is not defined.

```
$.each(Rdata, function(i, post) {

var Name= truncate(post.Name);
var Surname =truncate(post.Surname);        
var DepSubTown =truncate(post.DepSubTown);
var DestSubTown =truncate(post.DestSubTown);  

  content += '<div class="row white-text">'+
  '<div class="col s12"> <div class="card-panel teal">'+
  '<div class="chip col s7"> <img src="pix/pp.jpg" alt="Contact Person">'+     Name +' '+ Surname+'</div>'+
   ' <div class="col s5"><div class="chip" style"float:right;">R50</div>        </div>'+
 '<div class="row white-text">'+
 '<div class="col s12">'+
 '<div class="col s5"><p><b>'+DepSubTown+'</b></p> </div>'+ 
 '<div class="col s1"><i class="material-icons"> - </i> </div>'+
 '<div class="col s5"><p><b>'+DestSubTown+'</b></p> </div>'+
 '</div>'+
 '<div class="col s12">'+
  '<div class="col s6">'+
  '<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn"
```

Problem is here

```
 onclick="testy('+post.Id+');return false;" id="viewdetails">Test</button>'+
  '</div> </div></div></div></div>';     

});

$(content).appendTo("#Searchlist");

}
```

Comment: Post your testy function please.

Comment: Somewhere the parser is confused over which strings end where at your problem. I got confused, too; try to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer all i needed to do is add escape characters on the onclick function

```
 '<button class="waves-effect waves-light btn"      onclick="testy(\''+Name+'\');return false;" id="viewdetails">Test</button>'+
```